# Want to record calls of specific contacts only in recording app

Tags: java, android

I have developed a recording app which records all calls including incoming and outgoing but I want to add a feature to record calls of specific contact numbers only.

I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: There is this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927617/get-phone-call-information-on-android so maybe you can get call info and filter